# Coded UI Test Run failing on multiple tab

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I've been using Coded UI-Tests to test my company's web pages and I've run into this problem several times lately, unable to figure out a solution. What I'm trying to do is have a coded UI test click a link on one of the sites pages, which then opens up the link in a new tab. My issue is asserting that the new page is the right page, and has the right content in it.

When I run the test it will do everything else fine, it opens the link in a new tab, but the test can't seem to see whats on the new tab. I recorded the tests in the IE 9 environment, and set the assertions through the Coded UI interface. Is anyone aware of a way to redirect the tests attention to the new tab? Or what the issue I'm experiencing could be?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

This is the question raised at stack over flow [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098567/cant-get-coded-ui-test-runs-to-work-with-multiple-tabs-in-ie-9)

The only difference i have is that i am not recording anything, rather coding my way through action sequence . I am trying to find a control in the new tab using Search Properties, but i am not able to find them.

Can anyone please help me out. THanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the test can't seem to see whats on the new tab"? What elements can't CUIT find? Does it fail at finding the page or only when it tries to find elements on the page? Do you set the page visible before searching? Are the page's properties different from the given search properties? If you select an item on the page with the crosshair and then refresh the item will the recorder find it? (CUIT debugging 101)

Comment: I am trying to find an element using Search Properties, but it seems its done on the parent page not the new tab.Perform an operation on the newly found page , like mouse click or hover for example

Comment: Try debugging the test. Set breakpoint after the test control definitions and call Find or DrawHighlight on them starting from the top of the hierarchy (like NewTabPage.DrawHighlight(), NewTabPage.Client.DrawHighlight(), NewTabPage.Client.ControlINeed.DrawHighlight()). You can do this in code or use the Watches or Immediate windows. Then try to figure out why the search is done in the main page. Is CUIT finding it because it matches the search properties of the other page? Is it found with smart match options? Looking at logs can help a lot. Also post your code or at least the important part.

Comment: Kida, the search is done on the main page rather than on the new tab. I have checked it. How can i make the engine to check in the new tab. Is there any way to change the browserwindow's url to change to new tab or something like that , so that the engine will look in the new tab

Comment: Well firstly the tab you want to search in should be in the search hierarchy of the element you want to find (set as search limit container, passing the parent in the constructor). So something like: var myTab = new HtmlDocument(UIExplorerWindow); var myElement = new UITestControl(myTab); This will limit the search in the given tab. Now if the search properties of both tabs are the same then CUIT will find the topmost element. So you should set the new tab active first then start searching (you might want to call myTab.Search() first so it doesn't use any cached controls).

Comment: What if i find the tab using Title?

Comment: That should do the trick. If you can find the tab page and click on it, making the page you want to search in active, it should be good to go. As long as that page has focus, or it's your topmost element, CUIT will search inside that element (hopefully).

Comment: It worked , thanks Kida and sorry for the late reply :)